# Docker Options:[rbind ro]}]: permission denied when running docker compose build

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, permission-denied

I am some kind of new to Docker, I made my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml, it works perfectly on my local computer, but when I connect through ssh to the server and try to deploy my app it just gives me the following error while running:

```
sudo docker compose up --build
```

The error it throws me

```
ssh_user@viaticos2:/var/www/html/viaticos_nuevo/iec_viaticos$ sudo docker compose up --build
[sudo] password for ssh_user: 
[+] Building 0.2s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                     
 => [iec_viaticos-main internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 479B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [iec_viaticos-queue internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 479B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [iec_viaticos-queue internal] load .dockerignore                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CANCELED [iec_viaticos-main internal] load .dockerignore                                                                    0.1s
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to mount /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2469792042: [{Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/zqnkesva8mrrzin9w7ul4a9qe Options:[rbind ro]}]: permission denied
```

I have been searching for a solution but I could not find one anywhere, I tried a couple of things they said in forums, but I did not get to the solution.

I have to say again that this is working on my local environment.

Here are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apk update && apk add libpng-dev libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip

RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd mysqli

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
    main:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on: 
            - db

    queue:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: 'php artisan queue:work'
        depends_on: 
            - db        

    db:
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: mysql:8.0
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: viaticos
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_ROOT: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
        volumes:
            - dbv:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3307:3307
        expose:
            - 3307
    
volumes:
    dbv:
```

Comment: You seem to have included an image file in place of the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?  It will be much easier to read and search for later.

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions of composer binary using `chmod +x </path/to/binary>` ?